# Configure Angular 6 HttpClient headers differently for different REST / WebServices

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 6 app that needs to communicate with different REST API and old ASP.Net web services from different providers. Each needs different header information for JWT tokens and some also need to send cookies. Clearly I don't want to send credentials for one provider to another.

How can I configure HttpClient to behave differently for each service?
I understand the httpclient interceptors are global so even if I make multiple HttpClient instances the interceptors will behave the same.

Am I missing something really obvious? I had thought I would just spin up different instances of a httpclient and configure them differently.

Comment: Create an interceptor that sends the right headers depending on the URL of the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interceptor like this, and you can set different headers for different api's

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CustomInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (request.url.indexOf('http://example.com') !== -1) {
      // set headers for api example.com
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer token1`,
        }
      });
    } else if (request.url.indexOf('http://someotherurl.com') !== -1) {
      // set headers for api someotherurl.com
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer token2`,
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Make sure you add the interceptor to the providers array of your app module.

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: CustomInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```